# List of deprecated functions between php4.4 -> php7

Tags: php, version

I have a website on a server with php 4.4. (Yes, it exists)

I must move it on an other hosting with php 7
I've tried in local, and it's full of errors and nothing works.

For "scan" the files, I want make a script to find the old function and, after, one by one, "repair".
Most of .php are "dirty scripts", not well organised but my job is only to move this website and adapt it to php7.

But, I need to find the list of deprecated or incompatible functions from Php 4.4 to Php 7.

Where can I find such a list???

UPDATE:

I've find most of the problems in the main files (most problems are ereg function and mysql -> mysqli).
In the same time, I simplified the scripts because the developer used the same function with different name many times (8 times in the same file, with 8 different names -_-)
So I've made a function.php where I put all functions and I include it in the files.

It's not easy to work after a dirty developer -_-

Comment: Just fix the errors one by one (or rewrite the whole page), there are A LOT of stuff that has changed between 4.4 and 7... Make sure you got full error reporting on too, so you see all notices too.

Comment: I would suggest to make small steps for this migration. From 4.4 to 5 and eventually to php7. See this guide for more info http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.php

Comment: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer might help, but this is going to be painfull. How big is the codebase? A full rewrite with a modern framework might be a better option

Comment: There's 124 php files. I can't make a new website and I must use this because the owner don't what change the website system, only the hosting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Update: A comment brings up a good point.  If you upgrade fully to
>   non-deprecated 5.6 (get rid of any errors and code causing deprecated
>   warnings) you should be able to run under 7 with most likely just
>   Deprecation notices (which you can disable)

First, take a deep breath and figure why you need to upgrade from 4.4 to 7.  I can see the immediate value of getting up to a nice still supported 5.6, but 7 is a bit agressive in one sitting (maybe).  However, if you'd spartan enough for the challenge....

Got to the release history page and read each release from version 4.4 to whatever version you have available that you're looking to run:

```
http://php.net/releases/
```

Each version you care about should have a `changlog` link.  Click on it, search for 'deprecated`.

There are actually only 2 files one changelog for php4 version and one for php 5 version.

- http://php.net/ChangeLog-4.php
- http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php

Heck, if you get ambitious just write a crawler script in php to pull the pages and parse out the deprecated lines.

Once you're through correcting all the php 4 to 5.6 differences, take a look at migrating to php 7 (see my note at the top about running with deprecation notices):

http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php

Though some see it as a negative, PHP has been painfuly rigorous at maintaining quite a lot of backward compatibility, so I don't expect much to be off if  you're moving to PHP 5.3 or even 5.4 (around when they started deprecating a bunch of older php stuff).

Comment: I'd say that the leap from 5.6 to 7.x would be smaller than 4.4 to 5.6.  
Most php 5.6 code runs fine in 7.x, and all stuff that is deprecated or removed would (or at least should) be producing a notice or a warning in 5.6 first (with a few exceptions of course), hence should be fixed in the first migration.

Comment: @Jite  That's fair, if they get up to 5.6 and removed any deprecated stuff from 5.3, 5.4, and 5.5 they'd just get Notices for the most part

Comment: @Jite Added a note about that to my answer.  Thanks for bringing the point up for consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I find this list is better structured: [Migrating from PHP x to PHP y](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/appendices.php)

My team and I are migrating from 5.6 to 7.2 so I read in the following order to see what have been deprecated:

- [Deprecated features in PHP 7.0.x](https://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php)
- [Deprecated features in PHP 7.1.x](https://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php)
- [Deprecated features in PHP 7.2.x](https://php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php)